org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 's3Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
I was working on the AWS SDK v2 spring boot project on Java 17 using Maven and I tried to run the file but it gives me an error by saying "org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 's3Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 's3Service': Error creating bean with name 's3Service' defined in file [/Users/aswinshaji/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.0.RELEASE/webflux-demo/target/classes/com/example/demo/services/S3Service.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 's3Config': Injection of autowired dependencies failed". "Error creating bean with name 's3Service' defined in file". "Error creating bean with name 's3Config': Injection of autowired dependencies failed". I tried everything as possible as I could but I was not able to solve the problem. Can anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.services.S3Service;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class S3Controller {
    
    @Autowired
    private S3Service s3Service;
    @GetMapping("/listAllObjects")
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> viewObjects() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(s3Service.listObjects(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

S3Controller
package com.example.demo.entities;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;

@Configuration
public class S3Config {
    @Value("${region}")
    private String region;

    @Value("${accesskey}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Bean
    public S3Client s3Client() {
        AwsBasicCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey);
        return S3Client.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                .region(Region.of(region))
                .build();
    }
}


S3Config
package com.example.demo.services;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Object;

@Service
public class S3Service {
    private final S3Client s3Client;
    private final String bucketName;

    public S3Service(S3Client s3Client, @Value("${bucketName}") String bucketName) {
        this.s3Client = s3Client;
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
    }

    public List<String> listObjects() {
        ListObjectsResponse response = s3Client.listObjects(builder -> builder.bucket(bucketName));
        return response.contents().stream().map(S3Object::key).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

S3Service
spring.application.name=webflux-demo
aws.region=${region}
aws.accessKey=${accessKey}
aws.secretKey=${secretKey}
aws.bucketName=${bucketName}
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

application.properties

What happens when you change your @Value() annotations to include the full property name. @Value("${aws.region}") for example.

Is S3Client also defined as a bean? Can we see the class definition?

My code is the same as yours, and the errors are also the same. After modifying the version of s3 in the pom file, the error disappeared and ran normally.
  <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.52</version>
    </dependency>

